# Mocking of Resttemplate failed in spring boot junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I am writing junit test cases for the method which is call an rest api,following is the code I have tried:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class NotificationApiClientTests {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private NotificationApiClient notificationApiClient;



    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
          MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
          ReflectionTestUtils.setField(notificationApiClient, "notificationUrl", "myURL***");

    }    

@Test
    public void test_NotificationClickAPI_Call() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ResponseEntity<NotificationClickEvent[]> notificationClickEventList = util.getValidNotificationEvent_ResponseEntity();

        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                Matchers.anyString(), 
                Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), 
                Matchers.<Class<NotificationClickEvent[]>> any()
                                  )
                                 ).thenReturn(notificationClickEventList);


        NotificationClickEvent[] notificationArray  = notificationApiClient.requestNotificationClick(Const.NotificationClick, "2018-07-31-10");
        assertTrue(notificationArray.length>0);
    }
}
```

and in My NotificationApiClient , it was:

```
@Value("${notification.base.url}")
    private String notificationUrl;

    public NotificationApiClient() {
    }

    public UserInfoEvent[] requestUserInfo(String eventType, String dateStr) {
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(setHttpHeaders());
        ResponseEntity<UserInfoEvent[]> response = this.exchange(
                notificationUrl + eventType + "&dateStr=" + dateStr,
                HttpMethod.GET, request, UserInfoEvent[].class);
        UserInfoEvent[] userInfoRequest = response.getBody();
        return userInfoRequest;
    }
```

but it's not working, as per my code whenever the `resttemplate.exchange` method is called it should return the `notificationClickEventList`, But its calling the real api and returns the api result as the list.
Can anyone please help me to solve it?

Comment: Show the code of `NotificationApiClient.requestNotification()` please

Comment: @Lino I have added the code

Comment: @kaviya.P that snippet you added is not even called by your current code. please provide `requestNotificationClick()` method

Comment: You are calling `this.exchange` not the `RestTemplate`. So what is inside the `this.exchange` method?

Comment: Note that your test doesn't test anything. It basically check that you're calling exchange() with any argument, and that your method returns what you told the mock exchange method to return. Whatever error you might have made in the code will not make the test fail. Here's how you could write a more meaningful test: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not using `restTemplate.exchange` method, It seems you are using `notificationApiClient's` `exchange` method. So try this.

```
@Spy
@InjectMocks
private NotificationApiClient notificationApiClient;


Mockito.when(notificationApiClient.exchange(
            Matchers.anyString(), 
            Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
            Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), 
            Matchers.<Class<NotificationClickEvent[]>> any()
                              )
                             ).thenReturn(notificationClickEventList);
```

Comment: Maybe mention why you changed `restTemplate.exchange` to `notificationApiClient.exchange`?

Comment: Its not working showing me the error like java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'method' must not be null @Suganthan Madhavan Pillai